# php interactive shell doesn't have any output?

Tags: php, macos

bash-3.2$ php -a
Interactive shell

```
php > $a = null || "hi"
php > echo $a
php > $b = "hi"
php > echo $b
```

As you can see here, nothing is being echoed.
Why is that?
I'm using Mac OS X lion. =\
(fresh install)

Comment: too late to comment, but use [psysh](http://psysh.org/)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You've forgoten to put semicolons at the end of each line. Should be:

```
php > $a = null || "hi";
php > echo $a;
php > $b = "hi";
php > echo $b;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem:

```
php > echo $undefined_var
```

but after put `;` in other line

```
php > ;
```

Result:

```
 Undefined variable: "undefined" in php shell code on line 2
```

So, is possible make this:

```
php > echo 123456
php > ;
php > echo 123456;
```

Comment: Or, if you're like me, I had the closing semi-colon, but I started testing with an empty string. It printed an empty string, alright. Looks like no output.